# Handling empty JSON

Tags: java, json, rest

I need to send following JSON in API BODY POST request:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "type": "TEMP",
    "shared": false,
    "search": {       
    },
    "order": [
    ]
}
```

In my MainBody.java, declared

```
private String name;
private String type;
private boolean shared;
private JSON search;
private Object order;
```

and defined getters and setters.

In Payload.java,

```
    MainBody mb = new MainBody();
    mb.setName("");
    mb.setType("TEMP");
    mb.setShared(false);
    mb.setSearch(null);
    mb.setOrder(new ArrayList<>());
    
    ObjectMapper om =  new ObjectMapper();
    
    String myData = om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(mb);
    System.out.println(myData);
```

results

```
{
  "name" : "",
  "type" : "TEMP",
  "shared" : false,
  "search" : null,
  "order" : [ ]
}
```

Please assist with how search as { } can be achieved as per expected JSON instead of null.

TIA.

Comment: If you don't want a null, then you need to put real object instead of null. ie. `mb.setSearch(new JSON());`

Comment: Well, presumably, the result says `null` because of `mb.setSearch(null);`. (Rather, it was *already* `null` before that anyway.) Your JSON library gives you JSON objects from Java object instances, right? So you should create some kind of object in Java and assign that, right? Can you think of a way to create an object in Java, such that it would be represented as `{}`? (Hint: How does the library decide on the keys and values to put inside the braces? What should you do in order to make it so that there are none of those?)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting search to null, you need to set it to an empty object.  I'm not sure which JSON library you are using, but there should be an object constructor like `new JsonObject()`.  Depending on what the allowed values for search are, you may also want to consider representing it in your class as `Map<String, String>` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
    mb.setSearch(new JSON());
```

This way you create empty object and there should be only {}. It also depends on which JSON library do you use.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved after using JSONMapper.

Comment: Should probably show how it was used to resolve the problem so the question/answer is useful to someone else in the future.

Comment: In my MainBody.java, declared

private JsonMapper search;

In Payload.java, set as

mb.setSearch(new JsonMapper());